# what does きにするようにして mean?

Tags: grammar, syntax

A friend wrote me: 余計 ありがと、 きにするようにして
I know first part is "Thank you so so much"
second part I understand the parts, but I can't put it together into a decent meaning.
きにする is to worry or care about something.
ようにする is to try to do something.
I guess して is here not meant as an imperative, but because this part should be before the "Thank you" part (sentence order is wrong, due to last part being added), but even then can't really figure it out.
Something like "Thank you, that you try to care for me"?

Comment: It's gibberish, at least,  in Japanese.

Comment: 「余計　ありがと、 きにするようにして」 sounds (and looks) quite odd. It wasn't written by a Japanese speaker, was it?

Comment: true. it was written by a Korean, who has N1-level though...
I thought it was just very colloquial, with the wrong order. it was a text message, so I thought it was like when you already said "Thank you" and then decide to add what exactly for. something you maybe say in spoken language, but wouldn't write. but my Japanese (especially speaking) is not that good, so I don't know :)

Comment: The reversed order isn't the problem. The use of 余計 is strange, and きにするようにして is unnatural. To say "Thank you {all the more / even more} for caring about me," I'd say 「気にしてくれて/気にかけてくれて、(なおのこと)ありがとう。」 or 「(なおのこと)ありがとう、気にしてくれて/気にかけてくれて。」

Answer (score 2, accepted):

~して can be used as the connective form of a verb in addition to being an imperative, so you're correct about it coming before the "Thank you" part.

However, ~ようにする can also mean "making it a point to do~".

To put it all together, I would translate 余計　ありがと、 きにするようにして as "Thank you so much for taking the time to care about me."

Comment: thank you! I didn't know about this meanins of ~ようにする. this makes sense now.